# Age of Wonders 1 unit overview

Tags: age-of-wonders

I've been a huge fan of the Age of Wonders franchise and with the third installment just released I started pondering what units were available in the first version of the game (nostalgia can do that to you).

Unfortunately the Wikia on AoW is far from complete, so I'm wondering if anyone knows a good and complete unit overview for AoW1? I'm thinking of something like:

[image: enter link description here]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this list might be way to long for the Arqade format. I don't have Age of Wonders, but based on the unitlist in AoW3, this is going to be a long list.

Comment: I meant in a graphical form, I'll update with an example of another game

Comment: Ah, some kind of unit tech tree. That sounds a lot better. Still pretty large though, since there are so many races I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heavengames has been an effective wiki for the first Age of Wonders games.

[This page](http://aow.heavengames.com/units/index.shtml) has compiled a list of units in Age of Wonders, by race, in a tech tree format. See images for part of the regular and printer-friendly versions.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about that site and it didn't come up when I was Googling for it